# Flex items overflowing in IE11

Tags: css, flexbox, internet-explorer-11

I have a Flexbox container that's part of a two column container. This all looks good in Chrome, FF, etc except IE11. It has two children:

```
.container 
  h3 Title
  p body
```

and my container:

```
display: flex;
align-items: center;
justify-content: center;
flex-direction: column;
padding: 45px 25px;
position: relative;
```

and it looks like this in IE11:

[image]

where it's cut off on both sides.

I've tried adding `flex-basis`, `flex: 0 1 [...]`, `max-width`, `overflow: hidden` but to no avail. It still won't stop the cut offs. Is there anything i'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

I fixed it. Weirdly adding `width: 100%` to my `p` tag fixes it.